# Create vm and configure it in the same playbook

Tags: azure, amazon-web-services, configuration, ansible, google-cloud-platform

I have a playbook where I create a set of keys and create vm's and import public keys into those VMs. How do I add those keys to ansible in the same playbook and configure those VMs?

The private keys are protected with a password, so I plan to use ssh add + script to automate that, but is there a better way? Also, will ansible pick up those vm's as hosts if they were not existent in ansible hosts before playbook started? If not, how do I make this fully automated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add keys using Ansible's [authorized_keys](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/authorized_key_module.html). Examples at the bottom of the page.
2. `ssh_add` to manage private keys is a good approach
3. Use [add_hosts](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/add_host_module.html) to playbook's in-memory inventory to add new VMs to the inventory. Examples at the bottom of the page.

Comment: any convenient way to do so? talking about ssh_add. or rather, a better way?